# I bulit a small oop program and I don't know why it won't compile

Tags: c++, oop

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  Oseba akk("kreso");
  akk.printing();
}

class Oseba{
public:
  string Ime;

  Oseba(){}

  Oseba(string _Ime){
    Ime=_Ime;
  }

  void printing(){
    cout << Ime << endl;
  }
};
```

These are the errors:

```
error C2065: 'Oseba' : undeclared identifier
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'akk'
error C3861: 'akk': identifier not found
error C2065: 'akk' : undeclared identifier
error C2228: left of '.Izpis' must have class/struct/union
```

Comment: Declare your classes and your functions before using them! (in this case, before the `main`)

Comment: Quickest fix would be to move the definitions for your class and function on top of main()

Answer (score 2):

You are using a class which are defined after the main. Define your class before the main and it's solve the error at the compilation.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;


class Oseba{
public:
    string Ime;

    Oseba(){}

    Oseba(string _Ime){
        Ime=_Ime;
    }

    void printing(){
        cout << Ime << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Oseba akk("kreso");
    akk.printing();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You find those errors because the functions have been declared before your `main` function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class Oseba{
public:
    string Ime;

    Oseba(){}

    Oseba(string _Ime){
        Ime=_Ime;
    }

    void printing(){
        cout << Ime << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Oseba akk("kreso");
    akk.printing();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know what `Oseba akk("kreso");` is. The reason for this is because the source file is interpreted top to bottom.

You need to either declare the class before `int main()`, or put the class into another file and then include that file.